# In android studio which is the difference between an full screen activity and an empty one?

Tags: android

I wanna put some custom buttons in the application and the tutorial I'm following is using an empty activity,is there any difference?I want a full screen application but If I can build it from the empty activity its fine.And I have problems running my buttons while using the full screen activity even tho I did just some basic stuff from a tutorial.

[here are the errors for the full screen activity where I didn't touch anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTMtx.png)

[here are codes for my custom buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yhn7s.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can build anything you want from an empty activity. The other options that Android Studio provides are templates just for convenience, and include some scaffolded code to save time. Try adding both and comparing what the code looks like.

Comment: Yes I've seen the full screen is more complex,I wonder why it interfere with my buttons,I've found some errors even tho I didn't changed anything in "FullscreenActivity.java"

Comment: mVisible = true;
        mControlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
        mContentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);

Comment: findViewById(R.id.dummy_button).setOnTouchListener(mDelayHideTouchListener);

Comment: the fullscreen_content_controls and dummy_button is pointed with red

Comment: should i make a screenshot?

Comment: Please edit your original question to add this information, including the full activity

Comment: I've edited and posted 2 pictures I hope I did it right

Comment: Please add your code as text snippets in the future. That being said, the reason you are having this issue is that you aren't defining the IDs that your activity is looking for. The only ID you've added is `btn`, which isn't used

Comment: fair enough..since I deleted everything in order to be clear for buttons,I didn't expect that thank you Kai and yes I will post the code as text next time sorry if I wasted your time and thanks again